# react-redux: how do you access the store from 'anywhere' without importing it?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In the react-redux documentation it states that when using React-redux and `connect()` importing the store is not recommended. It's an anti-pattern.

> ```
> http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/StoreSetup.html
> ```
>
> Similarly, while you can reference your store instance by importing it
>   directly, this is not a recommended pattern in Redux. If you create a
>   store instance and export it from a module, it will become a
>   singleton. This means it will be harder to isolate a Redux app as a
>   component of a larger app, if this is ever necessary, or to enable
>   server rendering, because on the server you want to create separate
>   store instances for every request.
>
> With React Redux, the wrapper classes generated by the connect()
>   function do actually look for props.store if it exists, but it's best
>   if you wrap your root component in  and let
>   React Redux worry about passing the store down. This way components
>   don't need to worry about importing a store module, and isolating a
>   Redux app or enabling server rendering is much easier to do later.

How, then, do I access the `store` from any component  of my choosing(even deep down in the application) once I've properly wired in the `store` to my app?  My code properly connects `App` but I can't get access to the store from any child components at all.  `store.dispatch()` is null, `store.getState()` is null, etc.  I feel that the documentation is lacking in this regard. It's said to be magic but I'd like to know how to use the magic.  Do I need to write `mapDispatchToProps()` again and again for every single container component?  A use case would be the `currentUser` prop that would be available to every single child component in the application. I'd like to pass that down from `App` to every single child.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);//App is now a connected component, that part is working
```

Inside `App` I have a `Login` component, and I'd like to `dispatch` an `action` inside it. But I need a reference to `store`, but apparently I'm not supposed to `import` it.

Comment: It may be that they expect your data to be passed downward from the top through properties instead of each component getting the data it needs directly from the store.  Do you have a link to the indicated part of the documentation?

Answer (score 4):

This is where the concept of [containers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#presentational-and-container-components) come into play.

Suppose you wanted to render a `Login` component inside of your `App`. You will make a *connected container*.

Step 1 is to create a simple action:

```
const LOGIN_ATTEMPT = 'auth/LOGIN_ATTEMPT';

export const login = name => ({
  type: LOGIN_ATTEMPT,
  payload: { name },
});
```

You will now use `react-redux` in order to connect this action to your "presentational component". This will come through to the component as a `prop`.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { login } from 'actions/auth';       // your action
import Login from 'components/auth/Login';  // your component to connect it to.

// state refers to the "current state" of your store.
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ currentUser: state.auth.user });

// dispatch refers to `store.dispatch`
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  // calling this is like calling `store.dispatch(login(...params))`
  login: bindActionCreators(login, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

This `connect` function will take these two functions as parameters. You can now import this *connected container* and use it with the functions "bound" to it as properties.

Example component below.

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    // properties below come from connect function above.
    currentUser: PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  state = { name: "" };

  onChange = ({ target: { value: name } }) => this.setState({ name });

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(this.state.name);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          placeholder="name"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice, you never had to reference the store.

Comment: Thanks! Question: how would I access the store from App's 'grandchild' or 'great grandchild' without importing it?

Comment: Do I need to make a container component for App's grandchild and access the store that way? That seems to totally defeat the purpose of being able to access the store from anywhere.

Comment: You can either pass it to the grandchild via props, or import the container in the grandchild and use that. As for the second comment, on a very large app that might have hundreds of actions, it would be prone to error and over-bloated to use the store manually.